# Position of adverb 'globally' in sentence and meaning of sentence

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives, adverbs, word-order

Please help me make sense of this sentence with regards to 'globally'.

> In the global arena, xxxxxx has been
>   described as the solution to the
>   challenges facing the commodities market globally  as a result of the
>   market situation caused by the current
>   global economic crisis.

Would placing *global* in front of *challenges* change the meaning of the sentence?

> In the global arena, xxxxxx has been
>   described as the solution to the
>   global challenges facing the commodities market as a result of the
>   market situation caused by the current
>   global economic crisis.

Are there other ways of writing this sentence to make the different meanings clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to prefer "global challenges" to "challenges facing the commodities market globally," but both sentences overuse use *global*. I would suggest dropping the first clause altogether, and recasting the sentence to something like this:

> XXX has been described as a solution to the global challenges that face the commodities market during the current economic crisis.

or

> XXX has been described as a solution to the challenges that face the commodities market during the current global economic crisis.

Comment: +1; one "global" is plenty, although I think there's a slight difference between "global challenges" and "challenges facing the commodities market globally". The first suggests a consistent set of challenges that occur world-wide; the second could refer to different challenges in different parts of the world (rioting in Africa, starving in Spain, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Both mean essentially the same thing; the difference in position makes little difference.

As for rewriting, I would say there are too many globals and 'globallys'. It's also a bit long-winded after the first 'market'.

'Global economic crisis' is fine as it is though, so I would go with:

> In the global arena, xxxx has been described as the solution to the challenges facing the commodities market as a result of the current global economic crisis.

'In the global arena' already conveys the sense that both the 'challenges' and 'commodities market' are global.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely and utterly drop **all** the globals.

The "commodities market" is one particular thing.  (It's like referring to, oh, a particular company or a particular building.)

For example, you can literally go see and watch the GC market (the gold "commodities" market) being traded in a viewing gallery at a certain place.

"global commodities" market is as wholly redundant as saying, for example, "the nationwide! US Dollar" when you happen to be mentioning the US Dollar, or for example the "international! Nobel Prize" - there's only the one Nobel prize; it's completely redundant mentioning that it's global.